# Is there a transaction instruction verification system in place to avoid verifying user-fed transaction id's in a server?

Tags: transactions, web3.js, instructions, hashing, verify

Is there an efficient way to solve the verification of a particular transaction in the server? For example, I want the user to transfer 100 XYZ tokens. But while confirming the transaction in the server, I don't want to check the transfer instructions. Is there a nonce/hashing mechanism that can be used here? This leads to unnecessary fetching of the transaction instructions and double verifying them.

Answer (score 1):

If all you care about is the movement of tokens from account to account, you can use the [`getTransaction`](https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#gettransaction) API.

The relevant parts of the response are these:

- `result.meta.{pre|post}Balances` – Array of u64 lamport balances from before/after the transaction was processed
- `result.meta.{pre|post}TokenBalances` – List of token balances from before/after the transaction was processed or omitted if token balance recording was not yet enabled during this transaction. Read more about this data structure [here](https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#token-balances-structure).

The balances are in the same order as the accounts in `result.transaction.message.accountKeys`.